# sql query sum count

Tags: sql, count, sum, aggregate-functions

I have a table

```
id  date      state
1   10.01.01  reg
2   08.01.01  reg
3   05.01.01  check
4   02.01.01  check
5   01.01.01  reg
```

and want to show result like this

```
count   reg
5       1
```

e.g sum of "reg" statuses should be counted only if the previous status was "check".
Please, help me or give the right direction to solve it

Comment: What is your DB engine and Version

Answer (score 2):

In **`SQL Server 2012` and above** you could use LAG to access the previous row value:

**SQL SERVER 2012**

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
  select id, date,state,lag(state,1) over(order by id) as prevstate
  from Table1
)
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'reg' AND prevstate = 'check' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM MyCTE
```

[**Fiddler Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/008be/3)

**ORACLE**

```
With T AS
(
select "id", "date", "state",  lag("state",1) over(order by "id") as "prevstate"
from Table1
)
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(CASE WHEN "state" = 'reg' AND "prevstate" = 'check' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  
FROM T
```

[**Fiddler Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1931/17)

**MySQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(CASE WHEN state = 'reg' AND prevstate = 'check' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM
(
  SELECT T1.ID,T1.Date,T1.state,T2.state AS prevstate
  FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 T2
  ON T1.ID - 1 = T2.ID
) AS T
```

[**Fiddler Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fe8f/7)

Actually the third case would work in prety much everything.